# How do WriteMessage and ReadMessage in Gorilla Websocket work?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm working with **Gorilla Websocket** and curious about how the WriteMessage and ReadMessage functions work.

Does the WriteMessage function send the bytes data to the client synchronously? Or Does the ReadMessage actively fetch the data from the server (according to the documentation, we need to create an event loop to call the ReadMessage function).

What happened if the server kept calling WriteMessage, but no one read the message (the client calls the ReadMessage function through event loop), is the data is lost, or is it kept until the next read request came? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the WriteMessage function send the bytes data to the client synchronously?

WriteMessage writes the data to the underlying network connection.

The operating system network connection maintains a buffer of data to transmit to the peer. Data is removed from the buffer when the peer acknowledges that the peer received data.

Write to the operating system network connection returns after all of the application data is added to the buffer. Write can block waiting for space in the buffer.

It is almost always the case that the application write call returns before the peer receives the data. A successful call to WriteMessage does imply that the peer application read the data.

> Or Does the ReadMessage actively fetch the data from the server (according to the documentation, we need to create an event loop to call the ReadMessage function).

ReadMessage calls read on the underlying network connection.

The operating system buffers some amount of data received from peer.

Read on the operating network connection blocks until data is available in the buffer.

> What happened if the server kept calling WriteMessage, but no one read the message.

WriteMessage will eventually block waiting for space in the operating system transmit buffer.

Use a [write deadline](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetWriteDeadline) to protect against blocking forever on a dead or stuck peer.

> is the data is lost, or is it kept until the next read request came?

The data is held in operating system transmit and receive buffers.

Application write to the websocket connection blocks when the transmit buffer is full.

The data is only lost if the peer application terminates before the peer application reads the data.

Answer (score -1):

You can find source code for that function here: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/c3dd95aea9779669bb3daafbd84ee0530c8ce1c1/conn.go#L751-L774

And it looks like this is is blocking/sync method.

As per tracking They creating writer here: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/c3dd95aea9779669bb3daafbd84ee0530c8ce1c1/conn.go#L766

```
w, err := c.NextWriter(messageType)
```

Then they are writing the `data`:

```
if _, err = w.Write(data); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

And this is blocking because they are closing connection in the last line of that function, so writing must be done at this moment.

This is behavior of `io.WriteCloser` interface returned into `w` variable.

---

> What happened if the server kept calling WriteMessage, but no one read the message (the client calls the ReadMessage function through event loop), is the data is lost, or is it kept until the next read request came? Thank You.

- You should set Write/Read timeouts.
- Library is not repeating sending the data for you. You need to implement this logic in your application.
- If server is up and receive your connection, (probably) it will read your message(if it is not stopped before perform your data).
- If you sent message and server was dead(did not receive your message), your data is lost.

---

#### Additional reference:

- The `w.Write` function: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/c3dd95aea9779669bb3daafbd84ee0530c8ce1c1/conn.go#L650-L675
- The `io.WriteCloser` interface desc: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteCloser
- Gorila Websocket timeouts: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetReadDeadline
- Timeouts documentation for Gorila: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetReadDeadline

Comment: Applications do not need to implement resend logic on write to a Gorilla WebSocket connection.

Comment: I agree if you do not need it, but in case of errors, for example if timed out or any other connection issue, you may have to implement retry logic. Which needs to be implemented on the application layer. @CeriseLimón

Comment: A Gorilla Websocket connection is unusable after a write error, including a deadline exceeded error.  It's pointless to retry write on the websocket connection.